# How to align text in ansible template?

Tags: ansible

I am writing ansible template and I want that the template will create ntp.conf while keeping the lines after the ip address with the same amount of space 
To keep the lines straight and nice, the ntp.conf should look like:

```
server   10.13.1.1
restrict 10.13.1.1    mask 255.255.255.255 nomodify notrap noquery
server   10.13.21.91
restrict 10.13.21.91  mask 255.255.255.224 nomodify notrap noquery
server   10.13.16.26
restrict 10.13.16.26  mask 255.255.255.224 nomodify notrap noquery
```

As you see the lines starting with 'mask' are organized with the same spacing but with my existing code on the template it not getting be aligned

Here is my code on the template:

```
note: restrict='mask 255.255.255.224 nomodify notrap noquery'

{% for ns in default_ntpservers %}
server   {{ ns }}
restrict {{ ns }}{{ restrict | indent( width=2, indentfirst=True) }}
{% endfor %}
```

I am getting on the client:

```
server   10.13.1.1
restrict 10.13.1.1   mask 255.255.255.255 nomodify notrap noquery
server   10.13.21.91
restrict 10.13.21.91  mask 255.255.255.224 nomodify notrap noquery
server   10.13.16.26
restrict 10.13.16.26  mask 255.255.255.224 nomodify notrap noquery
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [format](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#format) filter for `ns`:

```
{{ '%-18s' | format(ns) }}
```

You can find additional info about string padding with python format [here](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align).